# Shoud I be concerned if my swap usage is 100%?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, swap, ram

Recently, I've been playing around with flutter. Between running an emulator, using the browser, and using vscode, my system memory has been getting decently close to maxed out. My laptop has crashed twice now before I started paying attention to memory usage.

Looking at Ubuntu's system manager, I noticed that my Swap frequently goes up to 100%, even though I still have some free ram. Is this expected behavior, or should I be concerned?

Here's a picture of memory usage in System manager:

[image: Here's a picture of memory usage in System manager]

Comment: Given how little swap you have, that looks fine. As a rough rule, as long as swap usage is less than cache, performance won't be horrible.

Comment: I'd start getting concerned if I saw lots of page-out/page-in activity and high IO-wait rather than swap being full.

Answer (score 1):

Swap space usage becomes an issue only when there is not enough RAM available. You can reduce swap usage by configuring `/etc/sysctl.conf` as root. Change `vm.swappiness=` to any value lower than 60(default value).

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. SWAP is less efficient than RAM which is why you don't want to maximize SWAP usage.